# Insert the date of the previous day in Hbase Shell

Tags: java, hbase

I want to insert in hbase shell the previous day.
For the moment, I use

```
put 'RPT:RAD', 'rowKeyTest', 'c:i', SimpleDateFormat.new("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse("15/09/24 10:00:00", ParsePosition.new(0)).getTime()
```

It works, but can you use a new Date, or something like that ?

Thank you.

Comment: For the current Day, import java.util.Date
put 'RPT:RAD', 'rowKeyTest', 'c:i', Date.new().getTime() works.

Comment: I found solution : Date.new(System.currentTimeMillis()-24*60*60*1000).getTime()